# How to using interface module on typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I've a permission module(in utility) for react-native project.Exactly it is camera module.Mainly structures are open camera and storage camera.Sample interface which I have already created is that ;

```
interface Props {
    names: string[]
}
```

My whole code at below ;

```
const Permissions = require('react-native-permissions')
import React from 'react'
import {
    StyleSheet,
    TouchableHighlight,
    Text,
    View,
    Alert,
    AppState,
    Platform,
    TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native'
import Camera from '../components/camera/Camera'

interface Props {
    names: string[]
}

interface PermissionsState {
    status: PermissionStatus
}

type PermissionStatus = 'granted' | 'denied' | 'never_ask_again' | ''

async function requestCameraPermission(callback: (allowed: boolean) => void) {
    try {
        Permissions.check('camera', async (status: string) => {
            if (status !== 'granted') {
                const granted = await Permissions.request(
                    Permissions.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,
                )
                if (granted === Permissions.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
                    return callback(true)
                } else {
                    return callback(false)
                }
            }
            return callback(true)
        })

    } catch (err) {
        console.warn(err)
    }

}

async function requestDiskPermission(callback: (allowed: boolean) => void) {
    try {
        Permissions.check('camera', async (status: string) => {
            if (status !== 'granted') {
                const granted = await Permissions.request(
                    Permissions.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,
                )
                if (granted === Permissions.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
                    return callback(true)
                } else {
                    return callback(false)
                }
            }
            return callback(true)
        })

    } catch (err) {
        console.warn(err)
    }

}
async function onRequestPermissionResult(callback: (allowed: boolean) => void) {
    try {
        Permissions.check('camera', async (status: string) => {
            if (status !== 'granted') {
                const granted = await Permissions.check(
                    Permissions.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,
                )
                if (granted === Permissions.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
                    return callback(true)
                } else {
                    return callback(false)
                }
            }
            return callback(true)
        })
    } catch (err) {
        console.warn(err)
    }
}

export {
    requestCameraPermission,
    requestDiskPermission,
    onRequestPermissionResult,
}
```

Maybe I can use TODO for my raw code.Can you advice me about this situation.
In the end my mainly problem is some ingredients don't call and I don't know what call truely for camera permission module smoothly.Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: This question needs editing, as it's not clear what the question is...

Comment: Dear gilamran,I wanna a permission method for react native camera modal,It will be open permission option while camera will be open .I'm new at both react native and typescript ,I wrote this command but I don't have to use this method efficently,just I wanna ask this .